# Jmeter Cross-Platform Path config issue

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am working on master-slave Jmeter configuration, my data set exist on each machine on a different path for (macOS, Windows).

I use a global data set to fetch data for multiple thread groups.
[image: reading student data]
However, the variable/property can be different across platforms.

I also tried the JSR223 to check the, but still no luck. check out the below snapshot.
[image: JSR223]

I am trying to make sure that once I ran my test from Master (Mac), it also run on Windows.

Any thoughts how to do that on multiple platform setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is placing your test data under the same path which will be relative to JMeter working directory, this way you will not have to change anything in your script.

If for some reason you cannot afford this you can add a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan and use the code like:

```
if (org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(System.getProperty('os.name'), 'Windows')) {
    vars.put('data-path', 'c:/windows/specific/path')
} else {
    vars.put('data-path', '/macos/specific/path')
}
```

It will detect the operating system name in the runtime and you will be able to define an OS-specific paths using the above approach.

`vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, the above code defines `${data-path}` JMeter Variable which you can use later on for specifying data files locations. See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) to learn more about [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shortcuts exposed to [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, except that I don't see that I can add the sampler to Test Plan (as global sampler), but I can add it to a particular thread group.
I am trying to add this for all my thread groups, so is it the same as JSR223 PreProcessor for the test plan?

Comment: If you want to change the value for all thread groups consider using `props` shorthand instead. It saves the value into [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) which are global for the whole JVM. Once done you will be able to access the value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as `${__P(data-path)}` where required. If you go for this approach the best place to put the JSR223 Sampler is [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)

Comment: I think my question is a little bit confusing, I am going to update it for other people reference.
Please take a look to it and let me know what you think.